# OpenCart: Logged users gets logged out on success page

Tags: opencart

I am new to OpenCart.

An OpenCart based website was turned over to me, which I uploaded to our web host. In testing the website, I logged in to my account:

I made a test purchase and proceeded with a test payment. However, as soon as the success page is displayed, my account gets logged out. But if I click on any link within the web site, I'm back to having my account logged in again.

I've been trying to see the files/codes that are called right before and after the payment. What files do I need to look at?

Comment: What's the login/logout status of your user when you directly fetch the url: http://yourdomain.com/index.php?route=checkout/success ?

Comment: Yes the domain is mydomain.com/index.php?route=checkout/success at logout status. And if I navigate to another page, ex: mydomain.com/index.php?index.php?route=common/home, I'm back to my login status.

Comment: Did you directly accessed the url or got redirected to that url after checkout process? I need you to directly access the url.

Comment: What do You mean by *my account gets logged out* and *having my account logged in again*. Is it something about visible parts at website or about displaying some error or about redirecting You to the login/register screen? I kinda don't get it...

Comment: The domain gets redirected to after the payment gateway (DragonPay). I could refresh the page for direct access. Thanks

Comment: Hi shadyyx, I tried to put some screen shots but don't have enough reputation. Anyways, part of the page that says "Hello <user>" displays "Login | Register" after the payment gateway accepts the payment and redirects to the success page.

Comment: Does this happen when you use the Cash On Delivery payment method? It sounds like your payment gateway is at fault

Comment: This happened on both online banking and over the counter pay methods. I still got the same results. I am beginning to conclude that it may have something to do with the payment gateway.

Comment: I have same issue. what did you do for fix it ?

Comment: see the link. I have same issue, but my problem was 'www.'

Comment: Yes, the problem was the 'www. When the payment gateway directs back to the domain confirm page without the 'www' on the URL, the user gets logged out. But when I insert the 'www', the user gets logged in again. I'll request the payment gateway to include the 'www' on the redirect back to the domain